# Where is best place to store ObjectContext instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I using extension for Object, because it provides very short accessible string.

```
public static BusinessLayer.Models.SearchEngineEntities db(this object o)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return new BusinessLayer.Models.SearchEngineEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SearchEngineEntities"].ConnectionString);

        if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("DataContext"))
        {
            return (BusinessLayer.Models.SearchEngineEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items["DataContext"];
        }

        BusinessLayer.Models.SearchEngineEntities context = new BusinessLayer.Models.SearchEngineEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SearchEngineEntities"].ConnectionString);
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("DataContext", context);
        return context;
    }
```

So in a result I have execution string like:

```
"".db().Users.Include("")....
```

But I'm not 100% sure that is best solution. I hope you know better than me, where and how to store DataContext or ObjectContext instance. Maybe you know better solution...

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need an *Extension Method* to do this? You should abandon the extension method and use just a `static` method (and a `static class`). Also I found an article that I think it might help you:

[Managing Entity Framework ObjectContext lifespan and scope in n-layered ASP.NET applications](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx)